# Error when flow tried to create records: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user: 012000000000000AAA

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, record-type, create-records, invalid

```
setupForObjectWithNoRecordType() {
    let defaultRecordType = '012000000000000AAA';
    this.recordType = defaultRecordType;

    this.layout = null;
    this.recordType = defaultRecordType;
    this.loadFullLayout = false;
    this.lookupFields = [];
    this.updateRecord('RecordTypeId', defaultRecordType);
    this.getLayout(defaultRecordType);
}
```

The error in the title occurs when this code is run within a flow which is invoked from an action override on the "new" button. ( INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user: 012000000000000AAA)

It works fine for other custom object types.

There is one other record type on this custom object which is not assigned to my user, and the custom object that it does work on has other record types which are all assigned to my user.

Able to reproduce error in the dev console.

Permission sets and Profile have both been checked to include this record type.

Comment: That's the master record type. A user cannot use this record type if they have any other defined record type for the object on their profile.

Comment: But another object with almost exactly the same code associated with it has 3 other record types all active and able to be selected within the flow

Comment: you need to use a different default recordtype other than `012000000000000AAA`